# Change button value after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I have a function which returns bootstrap row and every row contains input field, textarea and remove button.

So I have multiple bootstrap rows as I am calling function for various time. After clicking on remove button I am changing border color of input and textarea just to indicate that I am not taking it into consideration. I have made remove button to work as toggle button so that it will add and remove error class that I am assigning to input and textarea.

Now I want to change the value of 'Remove' button to 'Add'. So that when I click on 'Add' button it will remove the style of input and textarea and it means that I can take those values into consideration.

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value, tag) {
return'<div class="col-lg-4"><input class="form-control" type="text" value="'+tag+'" name="typetag" id="tags" data-role="tagsinput"/></div>'+'' +
    '<div class="col-lg-6"><textarea class="form-control issuetext" name="comment" id="" cols="" rows="">'+value+'</textarea></div>'+
    '<div class="col-lg-2">'+
       '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove btn btn-default" /></div>'
}

 $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest('#issue').find('.bootstrap-tagsinput').toggleClass('error')
    $(this).closest('#issue').find('.issuetext').toggleClass('error')


});



<div class='row'id="issue">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" value="'+tag+'" name="typetag" 
     id="tags" data-role="tagsinput"/></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <textarea class="form-control issuetext" name="comment" id="" cols="" 
    rows="">'+value+'</textarea></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove btn btn-default" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `#issue`? Post your full code

Comment: That wall of text is not very welcoming.

Comment: @CertainPerformance issue is a id given to bootstrap row. I have updated the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener to the button and change its textContent according to the value of a global variable.

```html
<button id="removeOrAdd">Remove</button>
<script>
var remove = true;
document.getElementById("removeOrAdd").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(remove){
      this.textContent = "Add";
      remove = false;
  } else {
    this.textContent = "Remove";
    remove = true;
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: it worked..Thanks

Comment: @Pavan No problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward. Just add a click event to the button. The click event will give you an `event` (`e`) and you can then call the standard `.innerText` property on the element to set it. No need for jQuery here...

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('testButton');
let clickCount = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 e.currentTarget.innerText += clickCount++;
});
```

```html
<button type="text" id="testButton">Initial Value</button>
```

Comment: I'd use jquery just make it easier for fellow developers to read. Also jquery adds an abstraction layer on the event object.

Comment: I have multiple remove buttons. I can click on a particular 'Remove' button the only thing is that I want to change its text to 'Add'

Comment: @IamDOM: I disagree. jQuery has very little place in today's front end world. Importing an entire library just so you can have a cute little query selector is not ideal. `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` are two reasonable ways to select an element in the DOM. Importing a library so you can just do `$(<selector)` is pretty lazy. Now, on the flip side, if you're doing something like web scraping or something it might make more sense, but really, it'd be better to just wrap those native JS functions in your own so you can make your own little `$(<selector>)` like function.

Comment: ...and to the point of "making it easier for fellow developers to read"... jQuery is the definition of "spaghetti code."

Comment: Ok, I'll start writing my own APIs from now on. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/ecma-script-binding.html